# php looping next year from below code

Tags: php, date

From the below code im getting the current year months from current month

```
<?php

$month = strtotime(date('Y').'-'.date('m').'-01');  

$i=1;               while($i <= 12){
                    $month_name = date('F', $month);
                    $nextmonth = date('m', $month);
                    $oneminus = strtotime('-1 month', $month);
                    $monthnumber = date('m', $oneminus);
                    $month = strtotime('+1 month', $month);                 
                    $getmonth = date('m',$month);

                echo $month_name."<br/>";

                    $i++; }
```

Once December is done.I need to next year month how can i get that ?

for ex :

My expected result  is :

```
September - 2015
October - 2015
November - 2015
December - 2015
January - 2016
February - 2016 
March - 2016
April - 2016
May - 2016
June - 2016
July - 2016
August - 2016
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For more details [strtotime](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php)

```
$i=0;

while($i<12){

echo date("F - Y ",strtotime($i." months"));
echo "<br />";
$i++;

}
```

Check this

Answer (score 0):

I think you need this one..

```
function showMonthYear($offset)
{
   echo date("F - Y", strtotime("$offset months")).'<br />';
}

$months = array_map('showMonthYear', range(0, 12));
```

which will print result, just like you needs. Hope it will solve your problem.